# Query MS SQL for empty spaces(&nbsp; or \xa0)

Tags: sql, unicode, ascii

When exporting some data from MS SQL Server using Python, I found out that some of my data looked like `computer \xa0systems` which is causing encoding errors. Using SQL Management Studio the row simply appears to be double spaced: `computer  systems`.  It seems that this is the code for `&nbsp;`: how can I query MS SQL Server within management studio to find all instances of this?  things like `WHERE ColumnName LIKE %  %` are not working, nor are querying on `nbsp;` or `\\xa0`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used `WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%' + CHAR(160) + '%'`

160 is the ascii for "non breaking space".. which is 0xA0 in hex as per your \xao